# How to use "AND", "OR" operator in solr search query?

Tags: solr

I am little confused that, how to use AND-OR operators in SOLR search query.

http://127.0.0.1:8984/solr/collection1/select?q=category_name:kitchen&category_name:bathroom&reno_wall_colours:red&wt=json&start=0&rows=100&facet=on&facet.field=category_name&hl.fl=category_name

In above URL, I want to make a query like:

`(category_name:kithcen AND reno_wall_colours:red)` or `(category_name:bathroom AND reno_wall_colours:red)`.

Answer (score 0):

((category_name:kitchen OR bathroom) AND reno_wall_colours:red)

http://127.0.0.1:8984/solr/collection1/select?q=category_name:bathroom%20OR%20kitchen&reno_wall_colours:red&wt=json&start=0&rows=100&facet=on&facet.field=category_name&hl.fl=category_name

Comment: thanks for rply. but its not working the curl.
$url = "http://127.0.0.1:8984/solr/collection1/select?q=((category_name:kitchen OR bathroom) AND reno_wall_colours:red)&wt=json&start=0&rows=400&facet=on&facet.field=category_name";
 
 /** start culr for solr search response**/
 if (function_exists('curl_version'))
  {
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '30');
  $result = trim(curl_exec($ch));
  curl_close($ch);
  $solrJsonData = json_decode($result, true); but its working on browser only

Comment: but when i put this url in brower, it give the response.
what is the issue? plz help me

Comment: Use `urlencode` to escape the URL properly or use an actual Solr client to avoid having to do manual escaping (and parsing of the result set).

Comment: I have one more question that how to set priority in query.
means if i want to display kitchen set always on top and after that bathroom record. how is it possible?

Comment: you can use a boost to search term: `title:"foo bar"^10` https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser